# Login to a website using script

Tags: python

I am actually writing a windows script which on clicking will open my default web browser , open a page , enter my login details and then submit the form.

All I could do so far was open the browser with this:

```
explorer http:\\outlook.com\website.com
```

Since I could not find any resource which tells how to do this, I looked at python scripting and found two libs ie. `urllib` and `webbrowser`. I am know that `urllib` is used for scraping websites. But I am not sure how to simulate the same in a web browser. The `webbrowser` library has only commands to open the page in a new tab etc.

Please tell me how I can achieve this task either using python or windows script.

**EDIT:** I have my username and password saved in my browser so that it auto fills. I just want to simulate the 'ENTER' key press.

Comment: A similar question was responded here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14445208/python-authenticate-and-launch-private-page-using-webbrowser-urllib-and-cookiej

Comment: Think that is close to what I want. But I don't get the part of the cookies. I just want to access the fields and hit 'login'. I also want this to be universal. So people with some other browser as their default browser can also make use of this script.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python simulate keydown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11906925/python-simulate-keydown). If you want, later, to add more than a simple keypress look at [pyautogui](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

Answer (score 6):

**IEC**

For me the easiest to use option for controlling a browser from Python is [IEC](http://www.mayukhbose.com/python/IEC/). I find very easy to use for simple things like you describe.

> IEC is a python library designed to help you automate and control an Internet Explorer window. You can use this library to navigate to web pages, read the values of various HTML elements, set the values of checkboxes, text boxes, radio buttons etc., click on buttons and submit forms.
>
> Typical uses for this library include:
>
> - Writing test scripts to check your web application automatically.
> - Managing an online account automatically.
> - Automatically logging and downloading webmail.
> - Monitoring web based applications periodically for failure.

**Selenium**

If you'd rather avoid Internet Exporer (and who wouldn't?) then you can use `selenium`. To install it do:

```
$ pip install -U selenium
```

There are details for how to login to a site with `selenium` using Chrome on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21186327/fill-username-and-password-using-selenium-in-python). The important part is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

chromedriver = 'C:\\chromedriver.exe'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
browser.get('http:\\outlook.com\website.com')

username = selenium.find_element_by_id("username")
password = selenium.find_element_by_id("password")

username.send_keys("YourUsername")
password.send_keys("Pa55worD")

selenium.find_element_by_name("submit").click()
```

Answer (score 1):

All the previous answers are correct here is an example for Chrome and Facebook.
You can use the same code but need to change the elements it's looking for and of course you have to give it, correct url, user name and password

Note: this was test on Macbook

1. download the selenium driver by:

   ```
      cd /tmp
      wget https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.41/chromedriver_mac64.zip 
      unzip chromedriver_mac64.zip -d /usr/local/bin
   ```
2. The code that does the work is below and again make sure you change the url, elements it looks for and user name and password. ( assumptions, open a file name called login.py and copy and paste the below code in it and then make the changes)

   ```
   from selenium import webdriver

   from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

   from time import sleep

   driver = webdriver.Chrome()
   driver.get("https://en-gb.facebook.com/login/")
   elem = driver.find_element_by_name("email")
   elem.clear()
   elem.send_keys("YOUR_USER_NAME")

   pas = driver.find_element_by_name("pass")
   pas.clear()
   pas.send_keys("YOUR_PASSWORD")
   pas.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

   sleep(100)
   driver.close()
   ```
3. run it:

   python login.py

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/getting-started.html) is a tool designed to test websites, so it is able to manage a large variety of browsers.

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 
import time

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("http:\\outlook.com\website.com") 
time.sleep(10) 
username = browser.find_element_by_id("user_input_id") 
password = browser.find_element_by_id("password_input_id")
username.send_keys("your_username") 
password.send_keys("your_password") 
login_attempt = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@type='submit']")
login_attempt.submit()
```

To retrieve your default browser name you can use [webbrowser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html) and create a mapping between webbrowser class type and selenium browser driver.

```
browser = webbrowser.get()
print browser.__class__
```

Answer (score 0):

`u'\ue007'` is an enter code in selenium.webdriver.common.keys library.
You might try to press "enter" after you sent your username and password.

```
username = browser.find_element_by_id("user_input_id")   
username.send_keys("myUserName") username.send_keys(u'\ue007') 
password = browser.find_element_by_id("password_input_id")  
password.send_keys("myPassword")  password.send_keys(u'\ue007')
```