# some problems with python 2.7.10 requests

Tags: python, python-requests

```
import requests   #auto class
import webbrowser
import re

url='http://teaching.nkfust.edu.tw/Course/Login.aspx'
UserName='*****'
Password='******'
my_headers={
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36',
'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
'Accept-Language': 'zh-TW,zh;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4',
}

sss=requests.session()
r=sss.get(url,headers=my_headers)
reg=r'<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="(.*)" />'
pattern = re.compile(reg)
result  = pattern.findall(r.content)
viewstate   = result[0]

reg=r'<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="(.*)" />'
pattern = re.compile(reg)
result  = pattern.findall(r.content)
eventvalidation=result[0]

my_data={'__EVENTTARGET':'',
'__EVENTARGUMENT':'',
'__VIEWSTATE':viewstate,
'__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR':'EC620E5A',
'__PREVIOUSPAGE':'cMlf7B-ve9HBkgfrfv-q8AJ50_VEsc0av7p79gkEJJkZqg6TfVcScwYFuXh9Bxb7aIieofwU1eB980nSeO55lrEIVXs1',
'__EVENTVALIDATION':eventvalidation,
'Login1$UserName':UserName,
'Login1$Password':Password,
'Login1$LoginButton.x':'0',
'Login1$LoginButton.y':'0',
}
r= sss.post(url, headers = my_headers, data = my_data)
print r.url, r.status_code, r.history
webbrowser.open(r.url, new=0, autoraise=True)
```

I want to ask that why r.url=http://teaching.nkfust.edu.tw/Course/student/today.aspx

webbrowser.open(r.url, new=0, autoraise=True) this is open to 
http://teaching.nkfust.edu.tw/Course/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2FCourse%2Fstudent%2Ftoday.aspx

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. It seems you are trying to authenticate a session using requests, and then magically use that authenticated session in a web browser, if so, that's not how the web works. Check for cookies set by the server in your 'requests' session and then try to inject those cookies in the web browser. Although you can probably accomplish what you need using webdriver (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14445208/python-authenticate-and-launch-private-page-using-webbrowser-urllib-and-cookiej)

Comment: Because the server redirects to the new page. Have you tried opening the page `http://teaching.nkfust.edu.tw/Course/student/today.aspx`? If you do, you'll see that the browser is redirected to the new page.

Comment: how can open http://teaching.nkfust.edu.tw/Course/student/today.aspx with something ?

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question correctly, your url "changed" when using request.get(). This is a common redirect. So you just have to not allow it.

```
r=sss.get(url,headers=my_headers, allow_redirects=False)
```