# Open a requests session in browser

Tags: python, python-requests

I have logged into a website using requests and would like to know how I would go about opening the link in a browser and being logged in.

Thank you!

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html

Comment: @AlexReynolds Thank you for your answer, I tried that already but that puts me back to the login screen. Do you maybe know if it's possible to load with cookies or something?

Comment: I have no idea. That seems something specific to a browser and not Python.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14445208/python-authenticate-and-launch-private-page-using-webbrowser-urllib-and-cookiej